# What does next mean here? Python Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to use the Python Instagram API and came across a sample code on its github documentation that I don't understand.

In the fifth line, why do we put next? What is next doing?
Why aren't we allowed to simply write recent_media = api.user_recent_media(user_ir)?

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.caption.text
```

https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

Comment: next is a variable you are creating to get api.user_recent_media result

Answer (score 10):

The second parameter is for pagination. The API call gives you the first "page" of results, and if you want more results you need to get subsequent "pages".

If you want to retrieve as many images as possible, and end up with the list of media objects in `recent_media`, you can do something like:

```
recent_media, next = self.api.user_recent_media(user_id=userid)
while next:
    more_media, next = self.api.user_recent_media(with_next_url=next)
    recent_media.extend(more_media)
```

If you're limiting to 10 results anyway, you can check how many results you've got after the first API call, and then ignore the pagination if you already have enough. (Empirically, the API returns 20 *at present*, but that doesn't seem to be documented so may change.)

Comment: The `with_next_url` parameter is not specified anywhere in python-instgram's docs. Thank you!

Comment: @bad_keypoints I didn't have much luck with the python-instagram docs, I ended up poking about in the source and looking at an example here: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/blob/master/sample_app.py to find out about with_next_url.

Comment: wowww this answer is super helpful. Even in the python-instagram docs I didn't see this method and this is SO MUCH SIMPLER than what I was doing. Thanks!!!

Comment: I came here to make the same point about `with_next_url` not being specified anywhere in the docs... how strange they don't mention something so common.

Answer (score 3):

The `api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)` statement returns a tuple of length 2 in the form:

`(value1, value2)`

If you did:

`recent_media = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)`

`recent_media` would be `(value1, value2)`

but by doing:

`recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)`

`recent_media` is `value1` and `next` is `value2`

#### Example

```
>>> z = ('a', 'b')
>>> print z
('a', 'b')
```

But you can also do it as follows:

```
>>> x,y = ('a', 'b')
>>> print x
a
>>> print y
b
```

This makes it easier to work with the data. Instead of having to do:

`z[0]` or `z[1]` where z is the tuple shown above, you can just use `x` and `y` straightaway.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The methods with api.user_recent_media(...) returns two values, where the second is a pagination parameter.

Please read the doc [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) for more info.